# Installing Biopython on macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: python-3.5, bioinformatics, biopython

I am using macOS Sierra, I tried to install Biopython 1.68 on Python 3.5 at last I can't install it at all I got a failed result:(

I followed the steps and went to the folder Biopython then I put this in my terminal **python setup.py build** or **python3 setup.py build**

Also I installed Apple’s command line tools, Xcode on my Mac but I don't know how to install Biopython in my Mac

I have Anaconda Navigator 1.3.1 it is working very well but without Biopython package, I can't install this package too.

I'd like to use import bio without any problem

Thanks to everyone who will help me

Yours
Saif

Comment: What is the failed result you're getting?

Comment: After this command I got this at last FAILED (failures = 4 ) ... python setup.py build or python3 setup.py build

Comment: conda update conda
conda update anaconda
Then you are ready to install biopython with:

conda install biopython
That's it. Open Anaconda and start an IPython notebook. To see whether biopython works, do the following:

from Bio.Seq import Seq
my_seq = Seq("AGTACACTGGT")
my_seq
If you get your sequence back, it is working.
shareedit
answered Apr 26 '15 at 18:08

Stefan Gruenwald
1,5021516
add a comment

Comment: Thanks to Stefan Gruenwald the above is working very well : )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python provided by conda (including Anaconda and miniconda), you should use conda's package system to install additional Python libraries. In this case:

```
conda install biopython
```

Comment: Thank you! I just used "conda update conda" then "conda update anaconda" then it's worked : )